# Enabling auth_basic in Nginx displays 500 Internel Error

Tags: nginx

When I have `auth_basic` enabled on my website, all pages displays `500 internal error`.

Here's what my error log says:

```
[crit] 10250#0: *5 open() "/etc/nginx/passwd.d/dev.passwd" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

The permissions to this file are `root:root 640`. Changing it to the `nginx` user doesn't fix it either.

Any idea how to fix this?

P.S. OS is Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

The user needs to be able to read not just the specific file, but the full directory path.  One test would be to temporarily setting the file to world readable.  If it can't read the file, then it's a deeper issue than just that given file's permissions.  Once you have figured out where in the path the issue is, start tightening permissions again.